Selecting values ​from multiple columns
I have a dataframe with option prices, with option tickers listed by columns and trade dates listed by rows. There is also the last column, My_tickers, that lists the option tickers I have selected for analysis.
Code:
%%time
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
tickers=['SPY240920C00440000', 'SPY240920C00445000', 'SPY240920C00450000', 'SPY240920C00455000', 'SPY240920C00460000']
Opt=yf.download(tickers, period='1y', interval="1d")['Close']
Opt_sel=Opt.iloc[-6:-1, :]
Opt_sel.loc[:, 'My_tickers'] = ['SPY240920C00450000', 'SPY240920C00440000', 'SPY240920C00445000', 'SPY240920C00460000', 'SPY240920C00455000']
Opt_sel

Result:
Ticker  SPY240920C00440000  SPY240920C00445000  SPY240920C00450000  SPY240920C00455000  SPY240920C00460000  My_tickers
Date                        
2024-08-22      125.000000                 NaN          110.260002                 NaN           98.110001  SPY240920C00450000
2024-08-23      121.500000          117.830002          111.629997          107.720001                 NaN  SPY240920C00440000
2024-08-26      122.190002          117.430000          112.389999          107.750000          102.459999  SPY240920C00445000
2024-08-27      122.800003          118.290001          113.529999          108.550003          103.250000  SPY240920C00460000
2024-08-28      120.949997          115.860001          107.639999          104.769997           97.730003  SPY240920C00455000

I want to add a column 'Prices' that will list the option prices at the intersection of the My_tickers column values ​​with the column names. This is what it should look like:
Ticker  SPY240920C00440000  SPY240920C00445000  SPY240920C00450000  SPY240920C00455000  SPY240920C00460000  My_tickers          Prices
Date                        
2024-08-22      125.000000                 NaN          110.260002                 NaN           98.110001  SPY240920C00450000  110.260002
2024-08-23      121.500000          117.830002          111.629997          107.720001                 NaN  SPY240920C00440000  121.500000
2024-08-26      122.190002          117.430000          112.389999          107.750000          102.459999  SPY240920C00445000  117.430000
2024-08-27      122.800003          118.290001          113.529999          108.550003          103.250000  SPY240920C00460000  103.250000
2024-08-28      120.949997          115.860001          107.639999          104.769997           97.730003  SPY240920C00455000  104.769997

I am going to use this on a large dataset (1000 rows and 700 columns), so I would appreciate a highly optimized calculation (e.g. vectorization).
I tried this, but got an error:
Code:
Opt_sel['Prices']  = Opt_sel.apply(lambda x: Opt_sel.iloc[:, Opt_sel[Opt_sel['My_tickers'] == x.name]], axis=1)

Error:
[*********************100%%**********************]  5 of 5 completed
<timed exec>:6: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
File <timed exec>:7

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:10374, in DataFrame.apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, by_row, engine, engine_kwargs, **kwargs)
  10360 from pandas.core.apply import frame_apply
  10362 op = frame_apply(
  10363     self,
  10364     func=func,
   (...)
  10372     kwargs=kwargs,
  10373 )
> 10374 return op.apply().__finalize__(self, method="apply")

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:916, in FrameApply.apply(self)
    913 elif self.raw:
    914     return self.apply_raw(engine=self.engine, engine_kwargs=self.engine_kwargs)
--> 916 return self.apply_standard()

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:1063, in FrameApply.apply_standard(self)
   1061 def apply_standard(self):
   1062     if self.engine == "python":
-> 1063         results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()
   1064     else:
   1065         results, res_index = self.apply_series_numba()

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py:1081, in FrameApply.apply_series_generator(self)
   1078 with option_context("mode.chained_assignment", None):
   1079     for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
   1080         # ignore SettingWithCopy here in case the user mutates
-> 1081         results[i] = self.func(v, *self.args, **self.kwargs)
   1082         if isinstance(results[i], ABCSeries):
   1083             # If we have a view on v, we need to make a copy because
   1084             #  series_generator will swap out the underlying data
   1085             results[i] = results[i].copy(deep=False)

File <timed exec>:7, in <lambda>(x)

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1184, in _LocationIndexer.__getitem__(self, key)
   1182     if self._is_scalar_access(key):
   1183         return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
-> 1184     return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1185 else:
   1186     # we by definition only have the 0th axis
   1187     axis = self.axis or 0

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1690, in _iLocIndexer._getitem_tuple(self, tup)
   1689 def _getitem_tuple(self, tup: tuple):
-> 1690     tup = self._validate_tuple_indexer(tup)
   1691     with suppress(IndexingError):
   1692         return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:966, in _LocationIndexer._validate_tuple_indexer(self, key)
    964 for i, k in enumerate(key):
    965     try:
--> 966         self._validate_key(k, i)
    967     except ValueError as err:
    968         raise ValueError(
    969             "Location based indexing can only have "
    970             f"[{self._valid_types}] types"
    971         ) from err

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1608, in _iLocIndexer._validate_key(self, key, axis)
   1606 # check that the key has a numeric dtype
   1607 if not is_numeric_dtype(arr.dtype):
-> 1608     raise IndexError(f".iloc requires numeric indexers, got {arr}")
   1610 # check that the key does not exceed the maximum size of the index
   1611 if len(arr) and (arr.max() >= len_axis or arr.min() < -len_axis):

IndexError: .iloc requires numeric indexers, got []

